# Any faster way to compute an historical ratio, under condition of value, in a groupby object with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here a sample of the dataframe with two players and the expected output explained aside:

```
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| Player |   Result   |    Winning ratio (historical)     |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| K2000  | Lose       | 0% #first game so no hist         |
| K2000  | Lose       | 0% #0 game winned on 1 contested  |
| K2000  | Win        | 0% #0 game winned on 2 contested  |
| K2000  | Not ranked | 33% #1 game winned on 3 contested |
| K2000  | Lose       | 25% #and so on.                   |
| K2000  | Win        | 20%                               |
| K2000  | Win        | 33%                               |
| Kssis  | Win        | 0%                                |
| Kssis  | Win        | 100%                              |
| Kssis  | Not ranked | 100%                              |
| Kssis  | Lose       | 66%                               |
| Kssis  | Win        | 50%                               |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

To obtain it I did the following

```
df['sucess'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['result'] == 'Win' else 0, axis = 1)
df['nb_of_contests'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 , axis = 1)
#gives
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
| Player |   Result   | Sucess | Nb_of_contests |
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              1 |
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              1 |
| K2000  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| K2000  | Not ranked |      0 |              1 |
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              1 |
| K2000  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| K2000  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Not ranked |      0 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Lose       |      0 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+

#then the sums cumulated
cumul = df.groupby('Player')['sucess','nb_of_contests'].cumsum()
#cumul gives
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
| Player |   Result   | Sucess | Nb_of_contests |
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              1 |
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              2 |
| K2000  | Win        |      1 |              3 |
| K2000  | Not ranked |      0 |              4 |
| K2000  | Lose       |      0 |              5 |
| K2000  | Win        |      2 |              6 |
| K2000  | Win        |      3 |              7 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      1 |              1 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      2 |              2 |
| Kssis  | Not ranked |      0 |              3 |
| Kssis  | Lose       |      0 |              4 |
| Kssis  | Win        |      3 |              5 |
+--------+------------+--------+----------------+

#then compute the ratio
winning_ratio = cumul['sucess']/cumul['nb_of_contests']
#finnaly shift
gb_winning_ratio = winning_ratio.groupby('Player') #in order to shift inside group, because cumul is a dataframe not a groupby object.
winning_ratio_shifted = gb_winning_ratio.shift(1)
```

So, is there easier way to do it? Because here I think this is possible to simplify, but I have not enough skills to improve it. So do not hesitate to give deep explanation please. I want to master it above all.

Pandas version: 0.23.4 Python version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notice**:

For avoid:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

create default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then use:

```
df['sucess'] = (df['Result'] == 'Win').astype(int)
df['nb_of_contests'] = 1

cumul = df.groupby('Player')['sucess','nb_of_contests'].cumsum()
winning_ratio = cumul['sucess'].div(cumul['nb_of_contests'])

winning_ratio_shifted = winning_ratio.groupby(df['Player']).shift().fillna(0)

print (winning_ratio_shifted)
0     0.000000
1     0.000000
2     0.000000
3     0.333333
4     0.250000
5     0.200000
6     0.333333
7     0.000000
8     1.000000
9     1.000000
10    0.666667
11    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Or you can use one line solution with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with chain `cumsum` with `shift` per groups:

```
winning_ratio_shifted = (df.assign(sucess = (df['Result'] == 'Win').astype(int), 
                                   nb_of_contests = 1)
                          .groupby('Player')['sucess','nb_of_contests']
                          .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
                          .assign(new=lambda x: x['sucess'] / x['nb_of_contests'])['new']
                          .fillna(0)
                        )

print (winning_ratio_shifted)

1     0.000000
2     0.000000
3     0.333333
4     0.250000
5     0.200000
6     0.333333
7     0.000000
8     1.000000
9     1.000000
10    0.666667
11    0.500000
Name: new, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Just in case of, for other members, it could be necessary to `reset_index()` of the dataframe to avoid the error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`